# checking if one expression contains the next expression in regex

Tags: regex

I want my regex to allow alphanumeric characters, "/_-" and white spaces in between **but it must always have at least one alphanumeric character**.

my validation goes like this,

/^([A-Za-z0-9/*-]+[A-Za-z0-9/*-\s]*[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)$/

**It should accept **ABC_1-2-3** but **it must not allow 123 or -_/** alone

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: So what's the trouble?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: the trouble is that it accepts even strings like 123 or /-_ which it should not since it does not contain alpha-numeric character

Comment: hi @Fabien I'm using Javascript

Comment: These types of problems are a case where the regex is extremely simple, but it can't be gleaned what you're intent is from the description. `must always have at least one alphanumeric character` != `must not allow 123`

Answer (score 0):

The below given regex will capture strings with alpha-numeric characters with optional white space, hyphen and underscore in it. Try it.

```
([*A-Za-z]+(\s+)?([\d\-_]+)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost right, you need to add 2 *positive lookaheads* at the start to require at least 1 letter and at least 1 digit:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z0-9\/_-][a-z0-9\/_\s-]*[a-z0-9\/_-]$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v16T7g/2) (in the demo, `\s` is replaced with a space since the demo is multiline).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of  string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, there must be at least 1 letter (replace `.*` with `[^a-z]*` for better performance)
- `(?=.*\d)  - after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, there must be at least 1 digit (replace`.*`with`\D*` for better performance)
- `[a-z0-9\/_-]`  - a letter, digit, `/`, `_` or `-`
- `[a-z0-9\/_\s-]*` - 0+  letters, digits, `/`,  whitespaces, `_` or `-`
- `[a-z0-9\/_-]` - a letter, digit, `/`, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

The `i` modifier makes the pattern case insensitive.